# JUnit Test cases failing while running using Maven but works with Eclipse

Tags: spring, maven, junit

I have a Junit test case which doesn't work if I run using Maven. But the same test case works when I run using Eclipse. 
My Junit class is like this.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/test-config.xml"} )
public class TestDaoImpl { 
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestDaoImpl.class);

@Autowired
private MyDaoImpl myDao;

@Test
public void testMyDao() throws Exception {
logger.info("Called testMyDao()================");
     // here myDao is null and throwing NullPointerException in sunfire log.
     // But this works when I run using Eclipse.
List<MyObj> objList = myDao.getList();

}

@Test
public void testMyCode() throws Exception {
logger.info("Called testMyCode()================");
     // this test case works with Maven
List<MyObj> objList = MyClass.getList();

}



}
```

Comment: Where is test-config.xml located?

Comment: It's in the path src/test/resources

Comment: does this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571149/test-resources-of-dependecies-not-in-classpath

Comment: No it doesn't help me. I am aware of this situation and this is Maven's expected behavior. In my case it doesn't inject the DAOs. The other test cases are working with Maven.

Comment: Any one to help me on this??

Comment: The issue was with sunfire plugin. This is resolved now. But I don't know how to set this question to resolved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sunfire plugin was missing. When added it started working.