# Use the same log4j.properties for tests in a multi module Maven project

Tags: maven, unit-testing

I have a multi-module, a lot of modules, Maven project. Each module has it's own set of unit-tests. I want to use the same `log4j.properties` file for all tests. Do I have to copy and paste the same file in each module's `/src/test/resources` or there is a smartest way? I'm looking for the smartest way but no luck for now.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17405828/1901067 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/3571292/1901067

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of possible ways:

- add the directory with `log4j.properties` to the classpath used when running unit tests
- add the directory with `log4j.properties` as an additional resources directory, files from this directory will be copied to the target/classes directory for every module